# Is there some connection between Kernel density estimation and Empirical distribution function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) says

> The empirical distribution function is an estimate of the cumulative distribution function that generated the points in the sample.

and gives this formula

${\displaystyle {\widehat {F}}_{n}(t)={\frac {{\mbox{number of elements in the sample}}\leq t}{n}}={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\mathbf {1} _{X_{i}\leq t},}$

Another wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) says

> kernel density estimation (KDE) is a non-parametric way to estimate the probability density function of a random variable

and gives this formula

${\displaystyle {\widehat {f}}_{h}(x)={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}K_{h}(x-x_{i})={\frac {1}{nh}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}K{\Big (}{\frac {x-x_{i}}{h}}{\Big )},}$

This [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/91/257182) says

> the pdf is the first derivative of the cdf for a continuous random variable

## question

Is there some connection between Kernel density estimation and Empirical distribution function, such as the former is the derivative of the latter for a continuous random variable? If yes, what is the derivation?

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely.

**About histograms, KDEs and ECDFs.**

(1) Roughly speaking, a histogram (on a density scale so that the sum of areas of bars is unity) can be viewed as a estimate of the density function. A KDE is a more sophisticated method of density estimation. Generally speaking one cannot reconstruct the exact values of the data for either a histogram or a KDE.

(2) By contrast an empirical CDF (ECDF) retains exact information about all of the data. An ECDF is made as
follows: (a) sort the data from smallest to largest, (b) make a stair-step function that begins at 0 below the
minimum and increases by $1/n$ at each data value, where $n$ is the sample size. If $k$ values are tied then the increase is $k/n$ at the tied value.

Thus the ECDF approximates the CDF of the distribution,
with increasingly accurate approximations for samples of increasing size. Generally speaking an ECDF gives a better approximation to the population CDF than a histogram gives for the density function. (Information
is lost in binning data to make a histogram.)

[By suitable manipulation (a kind of numerical integration), information in a KDE could be used to make a function that imitates
the population CDF, but it does not use the actual data values. In my experience, this is rarely done.]

**Graphical illustrations.**

(1) A sample of size $n = 100$ from $$\mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape} = \alpha = 5,\,\text{rate} = \lambda = 1/6)$$ is simulated. The figure shows a density histogram (blue bars), the default KDE from R statistical software (red curve), and the population density function (black).

```
set.seed(930)
x = rgamma(100, 5, 1/6)
summary(x)
hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.035), 
   col="skyblue2", main="n = 100")
 rug(x)  # tick marks below x-axis
 lines(density(x), lwd=2, lty="dotted", col="red")
 curve(dgamma(x, 5, 1/6), add=T)
```

[image]

(2) Sampling from the same distribution, we show the ECDF for a sample of size $n = 20,$ so that the
steps are easy to see.

```
set.seed(2019)
x = rgamma(20, 5, 1/6)
plot(ecdf(x), main="n = 20", col="blue");  rug(x)
  curve(pgamma(x, 5, 1/6), add=T, lwd=2)
```

[image]